# Remove 'Server' http header from api response

Tags: apache-camel, jetty, fuseesb, cxfrs

I have an application which uses camel-jetty, camel-cxf to expose a REST api and runs in apache karaf (fuse esb). Because of security reasons, I need to remove 'Server' header from API response. I removed the header from camel exchange headers but still it returns in api response as Jetty(7.6.7.v20120910). How can I remove the header from API response ?

Comment: Hard to help unless you show your route and logs that display the headers.

Answer (score 1):

The jetty component, you can turn off `sendServerVersion` by setting `sendServerVersion=false` in the endpoint uri.

For Apache CXF or camel-cxf I am not sure if that is possible. You would need to check Apache CXF documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Got working by adding <Set name="sendServerVersion">false</Set> in jetty.xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

I added following line to jetty.xml and got server header removed.

```
<Set name="sendServerVersion">false</Set>
```